# Can't resolve symbol @string/create_user_account. Validates resource references inside Android XML files

Tags: android, android-studio

I got three errors come out when i do the activity_main.xml

Below Here is my output Error:

> Error:(12, 130) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/create_user_account').
>
> Error:(38, 133) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/create_user_account').
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\minzan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Below is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.minzan.qimobileandroid.MainActivity">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/create_user_account" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="textPersonName" android:ems="10" android:id="@+id/name" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/uname" android:layout_below="@+id/name" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/name" android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/name" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="textPassword" android:ems="10" android:id="@+id/upassword" android:layout_below="@+id/uname" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/uname" android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/uname" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="textPassword" android:ems="10" android:id="@+id/uRepassword" android:layout_below="@+id/upassword" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/upassword" android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/upassword" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="phone" android:ems="10" android:id="@+id/phonenum" android:layout_below="@+id/uRepassword" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/uRepassword" android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/uRepassword" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="number" android:ems="10" android:id="@+id/cnic" android:layout_below="@+id/phonenum" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Name:" android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_above="@+id/uname" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="User Name:" android:id="@+id/textView5" android:layout_above="@+id/upassword" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Password:" android:id="@+id/textView6" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/upassword" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Re-Password:" android:id="@+id/textView7" android:layout_above="@+id/phonenum" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Phone #:" android:id="@+id/textView8" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/phonenum" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CNIC:" android:id="@+id/textView9" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cnic" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_createuser" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/create_user_account" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView8" android:layout_marginBottom="42dp" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/viewid" android:layout_above="@+id/btn_createuser" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cnic" android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/cnic" />

    <!-- <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="@string/lastname"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/username"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/password"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/firstname"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_fisrtname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView6">

    <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_lastname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_fisrtname"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/et_fisrtname"
    android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_cu_username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_lastname"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/et_lastname"
    android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_cu_password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_cu_username"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/et_cu_username"
    android:ems="10" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_createuser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/create_user_account"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_cu_password"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_cu_password"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_cu_password" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Re-password:"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5" />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Phone #:"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="CNIC:"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />-->

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: String with `create_user_account ` id is present in strings.xml file?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK..my string.xml file is only like this:
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">QIMobileAndroid</string>
</resources>

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37156870/3981656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add "create_user_account" to your strings.xml file. like,

```
<string name = "create_user_account">YOUR_TEXT_HERE</string>
```

Comment: i added like this:
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">QIMobileAndroid</string>
    <string name = "create_user_account">Create User Account</string>
</resources>

That is what you mean, right?

Comment: yeah , yes. it means you added  "create_user_account" string id to strings.xml. after that you can access that id to java files or any other xml files

Comment: ...you are totally right.
Thz for your advice.
Appreciate it.